# How to trigger a 2nd command when a specific command is run in the shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

I'll explain my question with example.

I run `$ python manage.py` to perform some action.

I want to run another command `$ xyz` , just when any user runs the previous command.

Thus, from now on, whenever user runs `$ python manage.py`

It should run like:

`$ python manage.py && xyz`

I thought of creating an alias.
But alias variable can't have space between them?

Comment: Why are you typing `python manage.py` in the first place? It is really not appropriate to include `python` in the command. Instead it should be invoked as `./manage.py` if it is in the current directory or `manage.py` if it is found through PATH.

Comment: ...plus, if `manage.py` starts with a hashbang line (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) and is given execute permissions, then it could be named simply `manage`, and the user could invoke it using just `./manage` or `manage`.

Comment: Thats just an example. I am not really working with `python manage.py`. It could have been anything, like `grep a` etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could put a shell wrapper around a call to `python` (put this in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`... depending on your shell),

```
python () {
    if [ "$1" = manage.py ]; then
        command python manage.py && xyz
    else
        command python "$@"
    fi
}
```

But I suspect you are better off changing `manage.py` to run `xyz` at the end (see python subprocess library), or creating a shell script,

**manage.sh** :

```
#! /bin/sh
python manage.py && xyz
```

Comment: Within the function you need `command python ...` so that the function is not called recursively. And, of course, it must be `python "$@"`.

Comment: Or better yet, name your shell command `manage` and leave off the Windows-style extension.  Your users should not know nor care when you change from a python script to a shell script, perl, or even a compiled binary. They should just invoke the name of the command and you take care of the rest.

Comment: @MontyHarder Given the name it sounds like it is likely a django application, in which case `manage.py` is the name django will use for that file, and renaming it to something non-standard is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @kasperd Oh, joy.  An application that demands stupidity.